# Java Hungarian Number Format & Linux File System

Tags: java, linux, filesystems

I use hungarian number format in Java to format a decimal value which will be put into a file and put in to a folder in a file system. The following is a sample of my code.

```
NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getNumberInstance(new Locale("hu", "HU"));
DecimalFormat decimalFormat = (DecimalFormat)nf;
decimalFormat.format(decimalAmount);
```

The file is UTF-8 encoded. When the file is created for example lets say if the amount is 1000,
In a windows file system if formats correctly which is 1 000.
But in a linux file system it adds a special character 1Â 000.

Can anyone please help me?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Maybe the console you use does not support UTF-8?

Comment: Awesome. that was exactly what it was. I was using putty and when i changed the translation settings of putty to UTF-8 it worked fine. Thank you very much fge

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the console you use does not support UTF-8? – fge

that was exactly what it was. I was using putty and when i changed the translation settings of putty to UTF-8 it worked fine. – PsychoKiller